# Position the sprites image after transform scale to smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I am trying to resize the sprites image to smaller by using `transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1)` to make it reduce 50% of width and height.

I want to have an inline icons, but the problem is, after scale -50%, it will have a big gap between the images. How can I make the icon next to each other with 10px margin only?

I've tried to set `translateX(?px)` to adjust the space in between, it works, but I have few icons with different width in a row, it's hard to adjust to make every icon having same spacing in between.

So I am looking for a more flexible solution, how can I make each icon have 10px margin in between by using `margin`?

Please see the code below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2btaxfq/)

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg-icon_youtube {
    width: 67px; height: 50px;
    background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/myfoodkampung/image/upload/v1606119223/MyFoodKampung/sdzkqpl7vz6u7wnpv9m3.png') -10px -10px;
    transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}


.bg-icon_facebook {
    width: 55px; height: 60px;
    background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/myfoodkampung/image/upload/v1606119223/MyFoodKampung/sdzkqpl7vz6u7wnpv9m3.png') -10px -80px;
    transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icon bg-icon_youtube"></div>
  <div class="icon bg-icon_facebook"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

I'v moved `transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1); transform-origin: 0 0;`
to "wrap" and added margin to icon

**Edit-**
Maybe zoom will be right for you?

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bg-icon_youtube {
    width: 67px; height: 50px;
    background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/myfoodkampung/image/upload/v1606119223/MyFoodKampung/sdzkqpl7vz6u7wnpv9m3.png') -10px -10px;
    zoom: 0.5;
}


.bg-icon_facebook {
    width: 55px; height: 60px;
    background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/myfoodkampung/image/upload/v1606119223/MyFoodKampung/sdzkqpl7vz6u7wnpv9m3.png') -10px -80px;
    zoom: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icon bg-icon_youtube"></div>
  <div class="icon bg-icon_facebook"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately no, each icon will have different scaling vector. for example: youtube scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1), but facebook scale3d(0.4, 0.51, 1)